# Use indicator for downloading file in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have a Html.BeginForm(...) with a download button in it. When the button is clicked we enable a busy indicator prior to the submit. The form posts to the controller and the controller returns a FileStreamResult with the response headers like set so the file is downloaded instead of opened or begin redirected.

```
HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=downloaded-file.pdf");

 // Return from the controller.
 return new FileStreamResult(GetTestFile(), "application/pdf");
```

I need a way to now disable the busy indicator once the controller returns since there is no redirection.

Comment: Please post action function. I suppose you use `return File(stream,"filename");` What does form post to the controller ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai see edit

Comment: Can you tell me what you've post to controller ? I need this information in order to give you a solution.

Comment: We only pass it an int which is an Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that i recommend is to `detect when browser receives file download`

It referenced this [link](http://syper-blogger.blogspot.ro/2011/08/how-to-detect-start-of-file-download.html) and this [link](http://gruffcode.com/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser/)

The ideea is following:  it's sends a cookie (C# Generated) with the file (that you are downloading). Use a `window.setInterval` to query for the presence of a cookie at regular intervals and check its value,and, if you have that cookie you can disable busy indicator.